# Locate Bluetooth Inbox

Tags: android, bluetooth

Our app needs to grab certain files from the Bluetooth inbox after they are pushed from an external hardware device. Is there a way to programmatically find the Bluetooth folder location? On the Galaxy it's `/mnt/sdcard/bluetooth`, and on the Desire it seems to be `/mnt/sdcard/downloads/bluetooth`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no simple and easy way to do this via the APIs (although there should be!)

Two solutions that could work (depending on the usage context; the first one seems generally better):

1. On start-up, you app checks if there's a `SharedPreference` (e.g.) "bluetoothLocation". If it doesn't find it, the app searches either (a) the FS or (b) the FS rooted at /mnt/ (probably (b) is better) until it finds a File such that:

   - The `name.equals("bluetooth")`, and `isDirectory()`.

Then it saves the path, and there you go. Alternatively (depending on the context) you could,

1. The first time your external device connects, it sends a file with some long, hard-coded filename (e.g. `greoermmvemoper190erjvw0j9e2.txt`). Then your app searches through the FS until it finds a file with this shared, hard-coded name, and saves that location.

These are both far from perfect, and their viability depends on your context. I thought I'd throw it out there. Hope it helps.